# click on cell then its only under cell get selected how can i do

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sjaZ/9/)

I want to drag the mouse on cell and whatever is under cells gets selected. only its under cell get selected. if user moves mouse zigzag way then no selection be happen. How can i do that.

[image]

```
$(".csstablelisttd").live('mousedown', function (e){    

    //This line gets the index of the first clicked row.
    lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    colIndex = $(e.target).closest('td').index();      

    $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight");
    $('#tableAppointment tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).addClass('csstdhighlight');
    flag = true;
    return false;
});

document.onmousemove = function () { return false; };

$(".csstablelisttd").live('mouseenter', function (e){

    // Compares with the last and next row index.
    currentRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    currentColoumn = $(e.target).closest('td').index();

    if (lastRow == currentRow || lastRow == currentRow - 1 || lastRow == currentRow + 1){
        lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    }else{
        return;
    }

    if (flag){
        $('#tableAppointment tr').eq(currentRow ).find('td').eq(currentColoumn  ).addClass('csstdhighlight');
        e.preventDefault();
        flag = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/EAETy/.  I've tightened up the logic/code a bit.  Hope this helps and/or gives you some advice.

```
    var currentColumn, 
        currentRow, 
        flag = false, 
        maxSlots = 3
        $table = $("#tableAppointment");

    document.onmouseup = function () { flag = false; };

    //helper function instead of alerts
    var flashColor = function(element){
       element.addClass('red');
        setTimeout(function(){
            element.removeClass('red');
        },300);
    };

    $table.on('mousedown', 'td', function(e) {

        //store jquery this reference since we use it multiple times
        var $td = $(this);

        //set current row and column
        currentColumn = $td.index();
        currentRow = $td.parent().index();

        //are there unclickable columns and rows?
        if (currentColumn < 2 || currentRow < 1) {
            flashColor($td);    
            return false;
        }
        //remove old highlight if any 
        //(find it faster by adding the $table[0] context)
        $(".csstdhighlight",$table[0]).removeClass('csstdhighlight');

        //add new highlight
        $td.addClass('csstdhighlight');

        //set mousedown flag
        flag = true;

        //prevent text highlighting while dragging
        return false;
    });


    $table.on('mouseenter', 'td', function(e) {

        //no need to do stuff here if user hasn't moused down                
        if (!flag) return false;

        //get row and column for this mouseenter event
        var $td = $(this), 
            $row = $td.parent(), 
            rowIndex = $row.index(), 
            colIndex = $td.index();

        //don't let mouse cross columns
        //or skip rows (from too fast mouse movement)
        if(colIndex !== currentColumn 
           || !$row[rowIndex>currentRow ? "prev" : "next"]().children('.csstdhighlight').length) {  
           flag = false;
           return false;        
        } 

        //add new highlight    
        $td.addClass('csstdhighlight');

        //stop after 3 highlights
        if ($(".csstdhighlight", $table[0]).length >= maxSlots) {
            flashColor($(".csstdhighlight", $table[0]));        
            flag = false;
        }

    });​
```

Comment: can u do using my code because lots of other data i get using $(".csstablelisttd") mousedown and mouseenter ..i dont want to change code brains...:(